# Trying to create a pattern out of circles?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to imitate [a pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxm2Z.jpg)) I found on the internet, but I get weird lines in the middle and when trying to connect another set of circles on top.

Also, when I try to fill, it becomes fully black.

```js
console.log("grid");

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var image_b = document.getElementById("brown");
var image_g = document.getElementById("grey");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;



var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var side = 160;
var side2 = 150;



ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

function draw() {

  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  var widthNbr = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth / side) + 1;
  var heightNbr = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight / side) + 1;

  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < widthNbr; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < heightNbr; j++) {



      ctx.beginPath();

      var x = side * i + side / 2;
      var y = side * j + side / 2;

      var a = side * i + side / 2;
      var s = side * j + side / 2;

      var d = side * i + side / 2;
      var f = side * j + side / 2;

      var g = side * i + side / 2;
      var h = side * j + side / 2;

      var q = side * i + side / 2;
      var w = side * j + side / 2;

      var o = side * i + side / 2;
      var p = side * j + side / 2;


      var x1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var y1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var a1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var s1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var d1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var f1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var g1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var h1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var q1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var w1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var o1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var p1 = side2 * j + side2;


      ctx.arc(x, y, side / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(a, s, side / 2.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(d, f, side / 3.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(g, h, side / 5.3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(q, w, side / 9, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(o, p, side / 18, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;

      ctx.arc(x1, y1, side2 / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(a1, s1, side2 / 2.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(d1, f1, side2 / 3.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(g1, h1, side2 / 5.3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(q1, w1, side2 / 9, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.arc(o1, p1, side2 / 18, 0, Math.PI * 2);




      ctx.stroke();
      // ctx.fill();

      ctx.closePath();
      counter++;


    }
  }

}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about canvas Path drawings as pencil drawing on a paper :

Just after the path declaration ([`beginPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath)), when you say `ctx.arc(x, y, rad, 0, Math.PI*2)` your pen goes to coordinates (`x`, `y`), and because `x` and `y` are the center position of your [arc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) it will be putted at a `rad` distance from this center to draw the circle. Your `0` tells it to start at 3 o'clock, so in this case, we just need to add this `rad` to the `x` value.

At this moment, your pen is on the paper.

It draws the arc, and when you tell it `arc(x1, y1, rad, ...)`, it goes directly to coordinates (`x1+rad`, `y1`) and draws the new arc.

The problem here is that you never told it to raise the pencil from the paper, so you can see the line that goes from the last point on the first arc to the first point on the next one.

Fortunately, Canvas API comes with a handy set of operations, and the "*Raise_the_pen_and_move_to_coordinates_x,y_without_ruining_my_paper*" is simply called [`moveTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/moveTo).

By telling the context to gently raise the pencil and to move to the next first drawing point, before actually drawing the arc, you'll avoid all these trailing lines.

So basically, for three arcs it would be :

```
// initialize a new drawing
ctx.beginPath();
// here we can set it directly because the pen is not on the paper yet
ctx.arc(x, y, rad, 0, Math.PI*2);
// tell it to raise the pen off the paper
//  and to go to the next starting point (3 o'clock in our case)
ctx.moveTo(x1 + rad, y1);
ctx.arc(x1, y1, rad, 0, Math.PI*2);
// once again
ctx.moveTo(x2 + rad, y2);
ctx.arc(x2, y2, rad, 0, Math.PI*2);
// now we've got clear independents arcs
ctx.stroke();
```

And with your code <sub>(That you could clean a lot by using arrays btw)</sub>

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var side = 160;
var side2 = 150;

ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

function draw() {

  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  var widthNbr = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth / side) + 1;
  var heightNbr = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight / side) + 1;

  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < widthNbr; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < heightNbr; j++) {

      ctx.beginPath();

      var x = side * i + side / 2;
      var y = side * j + side / 2;

      var a = side * i + side / 2;
      var s = side * j + side / 2;

      var d = side * i + side / 2;
      var f = side * j + side / 2;

      var g = side * i + side / 2;
      var h = side * j + side / 2;

      var q = side * i + side / 2;
      var w = side * j + side / 2;

      var o = side * i + side / 2;
      var p = side * j + side / 2;


      var x1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var y1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var a1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var s1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var d1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var f1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var g1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var h1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var q1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var w1 = side2 * j + side2;

      var o1 = side2 * i + side2;
      var p1 = side2 * j + side2;

      ctx.moveTo(x + side / 2, y);
      ctx.arc(x, y, side / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(a + side / 2.5, s);
      ctx.arc(a, s, side / 2.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(d + side / 3.5, f)
      ctx.arc(d, f, side / 3.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(g + side / 5.3, h)
      ctx.arc(g, h, side / 5.3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(q + side / 9, w)
      ctx.arc(q, w, side / 9, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(o + side / 18, p)
      ctx.arc(o, p, side / 18, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;

      ctx.moveTo(x1 + side2 / 2, y1)
      ctx.arc(x1, y1, side2 / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(a1 + side2 / 2.5, s1)
      ctx.arc(a1, s1, side2 / 2.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(d1 + side2 / 3.5, f1)
      ctx.arc(d1, f1, side2 / 3.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(g1 + side2 / 5.3, h1)
      ctx.arc(g1, h1, side2 / 5.3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(q1 + side2 / 9, w1)
      ctx.arc(q1, w1, side2 / 9, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.moveTo(o1 + side2 / 18, p1)
      ctx.arc(o1, p1, side2 / 18, 0, Math.PI * 2);

      ctx.stroke();

      counter++;

    }
  }

}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

As correctly noted by Spencer Wieczorek in comments above, to get the result you wanted, you'll also have to white-fill the largest arcs, but I let you find the way to do it as a training.

---

Also, a small note on [`closePath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/closePath) that you were using in your code, his name might be quite confusing when we see the number of people misusing it, but note that it doesn't ends your Path declaration. All it does is a `lineTo(last_time_I_putted_the_pencil)`. In the case of closed circle, it doesn't have any effect because `last_time_I_putted_the_pencil === current_pencil_position_on_the_paper`, but it's often the source of a lot of problems.

---

And an other small note, for users a bit more experienced (probably OP in few days / weeks) :
Other operations allow us to raise our pencil from the paper : **the transformation commands**.
(mainly [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform), and its subsets `transform`, `translate`, `rotate` and `scale`).
These operations will first raise the pen, and then **move the paper** rather than the pen. This comes handy in a lot of situations.
And to set it back to its normal position, you just have to call `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`.

Comment: This is correct. Although I just want the point out the OP will want to draw a filled white circle the radius of the largest "grouped circle" for every odd row.

Answer (score 0):

As I was far too slow in responding to this question please consider this an addendum to the excellent answer already provided by ***Kaiido***.

---

When thinking about problems like this it is sometimes useful to separate the calculation of values from their application.  Of course, this kind of understanding only comes with experience, unless that is we can plug into the experience of others - which is exactly what sites like StackOverflow are for! :)

The image we're intending to make is made entirely of circles, so we can greatly reduce  repetition in our code by creating a function that deals with just that one thing for us.  Something like...

```
/* draw circle */
function drawCircle(x, y, r, LW) {
  context.lineWidth = LW;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
}
```

Although this function only draws a single circle to the canvas we can pass it values that can be used to  draw every element we need.

The reference image is built out of sets of circles, where each circle-set has the same (x,y) position.  If we know those starting co-ordinates for X & Y, and the radius of the largest circle in the set, then we can create a function to calculate the values we need and pass them into the `drawCircles()` function above...

```
function circleSet(X, Y, Radius) {
  var count = 5; /* number of circles in each set */
  var step = Radius / count;
  var ln_width;
  var rad;

  while (count > 0) {
    ln_width = count > 3 ? 3 : (count > 1 ? 2 : 1);
    rad = count * step;

    drawCircle(X, Y, rad, ln_width);

    count--;
  }
}
```

The while-loop reduces the `count` variable from 5 to 1 and line width and radius values are calculated before being passed into the aforementioned `drawCircle()` function, along with (x,y) co-ordinates.

The **conditional** in the first line of the while-loop says:

- if `count` is 4 or 5 then `ln_width` equals 3;
- or else if `count` is 2 or 3 then `ln_width` equals 2;
- or else `ln_width` equals 1.

The `rad` variable holds a value that starts at `Radius` and is decreased by 1 x `steps` for each iteration of the loop.

Now that the circle-set parameters are ready to be calculated all that's needed is to calculate the values to pass to the `circleSet()` function, that is; the (x,y) co-ordinates and starting radius of each set.

As your original code snippet showed, we can use two nested for-loops for this. one to deal with the vertical and one to deal with the horizontal, but first we need to make some decisions.

If we want to have 10 circle-sets across the canvas then the width of each set would be...

```
    var circleSet_Size = canvas.width / 10;
```

...and the maximum radius of each circle-set would therefore be...

```
    var circleSet_Radius = circleSet_Size / 2;
```

We also need to draw two lots of circle-sets to make something like the reference image, one lot for the 'background' and one lot for the 'foreground'.  So we need to determine the starting (x,y) co-ordinates of each pass as well as width/height of the area we want to draw over.  We can create a function for that too.  Something like...

```
function loopXYPosition(startX, startY) {
  for (var y = startY; y < (canvas.height + circleSet_Radius); y += circleSet_Size) {
    for (var x = startX; x < (canvas.width + circleSet_Radius); x += circleSet_Size) {

      circleSet(x, y, setRadius);

    }
  }
}

 /* 'background' pass */
loopXYPosition(0, 0);
/* 'foreground' pass */
loopXYPosition(circleSet_Radius, circleSet_Radius);
```

With all that in place we can collate our functions into a single script. But before we do that it's worth taking note of those values which need to be calculated each time a function is called and which values remain static once calculated.  Bearing all that in mind we end up with something like...

```js
var circlePattern = (function() {
  /* define variables available
     to all functions */
  var canvas
    , ctx
    , cWidth
    , cHeight
    , circleCount
    , circleSet_Size
    , circleSet_Radius
    , P360;

  /* draw each cicle */
  function drawCircle(x, y, r, LW) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = LW;
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, P360, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  /* calculate each set of circles (circle-set) */
  function circleSet(X, Y, R) {
    var count = circleCount,
      radiusSteps = R / count,
      ln_width,
      rad;

    while (count > 0) {
      ln_width = count > 3 ? 2.5 : (count > 1 ? 2 : 1.5);
      rad = count * radiusSteps;

      drawCircle(X, Y, rad, ln_width);

      count--;
    }

  }

  function loopXYPosition(startX, startY) {
    /* add circleSet_Radius to canvas width
       and height to make sure we draw right
       up to the edges of the canvas */
    var cHcR = cHeight + circleSet_Radius;
    var cWcR = cWidth + circleSet_Radius;

    /* to get the effect we want we need to create
       a little padding around each circle-set,
       therefore we reduce the circelSet_Radius value
       by 5% before passing to drawCircleSet() */
    var setRadius = circleSet_Radius * 0.95;

    /* step across and down canvas in
       increments of 'circleSet_Size' */
    for (var y = startY; y < cHcR; y += circleSet_Size) {
      for (var x = startX; x < cWcR; x += circleSet_Size) {

        circleSet(x, y, setRadius);

      }
    }

  }

  function begin(NoC, cCount) {
    var numberOfCircles = NoC;

    /* set variables needed later */
    circleSet_Size = cWidth / numberOfCircles;
    circleSet_Radius = circleSet_Size / 2;
    circleCount = cCount;

    /* draw rows of circles */
    loopXYPosition(0, 0);
    loopXYPosition(circleSet_Radius, circleSet_Radius);
  }

  /* initialise canvas */
  function init(e) {
    /* Set variables to use later */
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    cWidth = canvas.width;
    cHeight = canvas.height;

    P360 = Math.PI * 2;

    /* fillStyle & strokeStyle are properties
       of the Canvas, so we only need to set
       them once here */
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';

    /* fill canvas (background) */
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);

    /* first argument: number of horizontal circle-sets
       second argument: number of circles in each set 
       !Try different values here! */
    begin(7, 6);
  }

  return {
    go: init
  };
}());

window.onload = circlePattern.go;
```

```css
body {
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
div.box {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin:2em auto;
    display:block;
}
div.box h3 {
    font-size:1.3em;
    line-height:2.3em;
}
#refimg, #canvas {
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
#refimg {
    height:360px;
}
#canvas {
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <h3>Refernece Image</h3>
    <img id="refimg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxm2Z.jpg)" alt="image" title="reference image" />
</div>

<div class="box">
    <h3>Canvas Image</h3>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400" title="Canvas image"></canvas>
</div>
```

Not exactly the same results, though pretty close. With the exception of the (x,y) co-ordinates which pass through it the `circleSet()` function produces the same sequence of values each time it is called, so those values could be calculated once and stored in an Object, but I've included it here for simplicity and to highlight the sequence of events.

Feeding different values into the `begin()` function and playing with `setRadius` in the `loopXYPosition()` function yields some interesting results.

I hope the process outlined here gives you some hints in your continuing exploration of the HTML5 Canvas API.

;)

Comment: There are actually a lot of ways to do it, here is an other one, taking advantages of canvas `createPattern()` method : https://jsfiddle.net/d6bwm5jf/

Comment: @Kaiido Oo, I like that :) Yeah, many ways to do this: one could create an off-page `Canves` and use `.drawImage()` also. My approach was to give a clue about how a long series of steps can be broken down into a series of simpler functions.

Comment: Note that I actually do use an offscreen canvas too, createPattern is just to avoid loops.